# Falied to assign value to textview in a thread class

Tags: android

I have a textview in one of the page named txtdownloadStatus.I have thread class that downloads some data and if completed i want to show completed in the textview that is placed in the page i told earilier.

My user interface name is

```
download_manifest.txtdownloadStatus.setText("Completed Download");
```

The thread class is as given below

```
public class thread_download extends Thread {
    private download_helper downloadhelper;
    private Context context;
    public thread_download(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
     public void run() {

           downloadhelper = new download_helper(this.context);

            try {
                downloadhelper.DownloadProblemAndReasonCode();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                downloadhelper.DownloadNewManifest();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                downloadhelper.DownloadNewMessages();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            downloadhelper.DeleteOldManifest();
            try {
            download_manifest.txtdownloadStatus.setText("Cpmpleted");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

The problem is that when i tried to set value to the textview in the thread class.It shows an error like given below

android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Will anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

you have to run it on UIthread. as the error says any operation on the UI elements have to performed in the UIthread.

you have to use `runOnUIThread()` method.

Use `AsyncTask` , it creates a separate thread automatically for you and `postExecute` and `preExecute` methods of it run on UI thread . you don't have to do anything complex, if you use asyncTask, it was designed for this purposes i think.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the UI from a thread other than the UI thread. You should use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to modify the UI.

Answer (score 0):

In android all the UI stuff should be done on the UI thread. You can either use the runOnUIThread method or when you are done processing in the background thread, use a handler to update the textview. Your error will be fixed.